# What was the software used for gene sequencing in Rise of the Planet of the Apes?

Tags: props, planet-of-the-apes-2011, rise-of-the-planet-of-the-apes

Does anybody know what software was shown in this movie for sequencing vaccines?
It seems real.

[image: screenshot showing the software in use]

Comment: It seems real? The two smaller, boring panels on the right seem real. The colorful graphics in the main panel look to me like pure movie-grade eye candy. ;) But maybe I'm too cynical. There is an awful big list of software [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sequence_alignment_software) if you have some hours to kill.

Comment: Generic Sciency-Looking Screensaver with Cool Graph and Bluish Palette

Comment: I don't see how a question about the software in an SF movie isn't on topic, and isn't constructive.

Comment: @DampeS8N, if the software is real, then it isn't science fiction. If it isn't, it is just CGI. He isn't asking about particulars of a science fiction software, he just wants to know if it is real or not.

Comment: From our FAQ these are on topic: "Historical or societal context of a work, Behind-the-scenes and fandom information" - I'd say that information on a prop in a movie counts as the second, and information about the state of this type of software is the first.

Comment: It's a Unix system!  I know this...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm afraid the software isn't real.

Scientific/Research/Academic software tends to look like DOS/Windows 95 and Excel. Fancy graphics like those ones you showed are very very rare here because these tools are built for niche scientific audiences and without large (typically any) budget. Often they are built by the scientists themselves.

The image you show features really slick graphics and a custom UI for the OS widgets (the close/minimize buttons, the frames around the window, other UI components.) It is a LOT of work to code these kinds of things. These developers would not spend that kind of time on things that are 100% cosmetic. Especially since the default widgets are very easy to use.

Most UI for science/research/academic software is built with the WYSWYG editor in Visual Studio if they have it, or basic console style inputs if such an editor is not present.

Example Software:

- [A Tool for Genetic Programming](http://www.rmltech.com/products.aspx)
- [Raptor Reliability Simulation Software](http://www.arinc.com/products/raptor/)

Example Images:

[image]

http://software79.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/Scilab.jpg

[image]

Comment: I went through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_data_visualization understood this already. I'm software developer,so I've decided there is some commercial company which probably built something fancy. But after all, and your comment it seems NOT real. So I have a field to work on =). The biggest commercial software suite from http://www.dnastar.com/default.aspx there are a lot of features, but looks like from 90-s.

Comment: Just doesn't need to NOT look like it is from the 90's so why spend money to change? These design idioms are ugly, but still completely usable and effective. There are no pretty jackhammers.

Comment: @DampeS8N Ooh! Ooh! Ooh! Guess the SF quote time: *'[There] was an* elegance *to the [ship] that screamed competence. "The damn thing has the feel of a hand axe built in a factory"'* Answers in chat.

Comment: That [second link](http://www.arinc.com/products/raptor/) was *very* disappointing - it wasn't *at all* [what I was expecting](http://store.xkcd.com/xkcd/#NoRaptors).

Comment: @JohnC, Expecting software for maintaining your Raptor, huh?

Comment: Also. Things tend to link-rot quickly in this space. Half of the stuff I used as examples has moved. :(

Comment: This answer is interesting. However, two \*i\*mages — with a small \*i\*, like \*s\*oftware — are broken.

Comment: @John — Indeed. Especially now that [this second link](http://www.arinc.com/products/raptor/) is now… extinct.

Comment: Dang, even the xkcd link went bad - it's now [no-raptor t-shirts](http://store.xkcd.com/products/no-raptors)

Comment: Most of your links are dead. One of them was actively trying to give my computer a virus.